# How to delete multiple files in s3 using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script to delete a list of files in s3 that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
s3folder="$2"
while read -r line; do
file="$line"
aws s3 rm s3://bucketname/data/$s3folder/$file
done < "$filename"
```

When I run this, I see the stdout of the s3 delete command (Example: delete: s3://s3bucketname/data/foldername/file.json) so I know my s3 command is good and I know the data from my variables and input file are landing properly, there are no errors, but my files are still there after the script has finished.

If I run the individual aws s3 rm commands manually on the command line, it works.

I've tried every variant I could find of sourcing the bash profile and running the command as the user with s3 privs etc.

I've also tried the --recursive --exclude --include variants of the aws s3 rm command but that has the same results.

```
`for file in $(cat $filename);do aws s3 rm s3://s3bucketname/data/$s3folder/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "$file"; done`
```

If I run the aws s3 rm command in a script using a single file name as a command line arg, that also works so I guess it is something about the loop but I'm not getting it ?

Comment: Check your input file for [carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) characters

Comment: Yup that was it. Resaved the input file in notepad++ after changing the EOL chars to Linux, pushed the file over, re-ran the script and files are deleted. Thanks @thatotherguy !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turned out to be windows EOL chars in the input file. Converted them to Linux EOL chars and the aws s3 rm commands are working as expected. Thanks to [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) for the quick answer to my hours spent troubeshooting this !